# isometric isomorphism implies diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism, diffeomorphism

Suppose $E$ be a $\mathbb R-$vector space that is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ via the map $f:\, E\to\mathbb R^n$, which means $f$ is bijective and
\begin{align}
d_E(x,y)&=d_{\mathbb R^n}\big(f(x),f(y)\big)
\\ f(x+y)&=f(x)+f(y)
\end{align}
for all $x,y\in E$.

My question is if $f$ is a diffeomorphism ? I have no clue for this confusion, may anyone provide me with some explaination, some interesting idea ? Thanks

Comment: What’s your definition of a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Or, more simply, what’s the definition of a smooth map to or from $E$?

Comment: @Deane well, a map $f:\, E\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is smooth ($k-th$ differentiable) at $p\in E$ if there exists a local chart $p\in U\subset E,\ \varphi:\ U\to\mathbb R^n$ and a local chart $\psi:\ f(U)\to\mathbb R^n$ such that 
$$ \psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}:\ \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n $$
is smooth at $\varphi(p)$.

Comment: In order to use this definition in practice, you have to know which maps $\varphi: U \rightarrow E$ are local charts. Can you say which ones are for the standard manifold structure of a vector space $E$? Or, to put it differently, how do you know $E$ is a manifold?

Comment: $E$ is a manifold if it's locally Euclidean, do you meant ?

Comment: So is $E$ locally Euclidean? Why? You can’t do this problem unless you verify all of the definitions and assumptions.

Comment: I think let $g,h:\ E\to\mathbb R$ be linear isomorphism, then the map $h\circ g^{-1}$ can give a homeomorphism between each neighborhood of $E$ to $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: OK. Using all this and what you know about $f$, you want to prove that $f$ is smooth. Any ideas of what you could try?

Comment: I think my definition for the isomorphism $f$ should be linear rather than just additive

Comment: Is the definition yours or or did come from a book or lecture?

Comment: I think I just made some mistake in my assumption, since from what I read about isometric isomorphism, the map should be linear instead of just additive

Comment: Here's what I think

Given $p\in E$.

First, since $E$ is a manifold, (however I have no clue how to show that it is smooth manifold), we have a chart $U_p\subset E$ and homeomorphism $\varphi:\ U_p\to\mathbb R^n$.

Next, since $\mathbb R^n$ is diffeomorphism to itself, we just need to consider $\psi=Id_{\mathbb R^n}$.

We have 
$$ d\big(Id\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}\big)_{\varphi(p)}= df_p\circ(d\varphi^{-1})_{\varphi(p)} $$

Comment: The problem is a lot easier if you assume the map is linear or affine (composition of a linear map with a translation). Please note that a neighborhood of a point can be as large as you want. The cool part is that you do not need to assume additive or linear. That the map is isometric is enough to prove the map is affine.

Comment: and since $f$ is linear or affine, it should be differentiable ?

Comment: Yes, but you should write down a careful proof anyway. When you're first learning a subject, you should write out the details of even "obvious" facts.

Comment: but, to show that $f$ í differentiable on $E$, we still need the differentiability of $\varphi$ right ? So how can I get that ?

Comment: $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$ No. Read the definition of differentiability of a function $f: E \rightarrow \R$ carefully. It can't involve the differentiability of $\varphi: U\rightarrow \R$ directly because that's still undefined.

Comment: @Deane here is my proof : since $f:\ E\to\mathbb R^3$ is isometric, by $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, pick $\delta=\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we will get the continuity of $f$ at every $x\in E$. Since $f$ is bijective, we have
$$d_{E}\big(f^{-1}(f(x)), f^{-1}(f(y)) \big) = d_{E}(x,y)=d_{\mathbb R^3}\big(f(x),f(y) \big)$$
which means $f^{_1}$ is also isometric. By the proof for $f$, we claim that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^3$. So $f$ is a homeomorphism, and thus $E$ is a manifold.

Comment: Consider the atlas $\big(E,f\big)$ of $E$, we have $f\circ f^{-1}=id_{\mathbb R^3}$, thus it is smooth. So $E$ is a smooth 3-manifold.

Comment: Now, we have $id_{\mathbb R^3}\circ f\circ f^{-1}=id_{\mathbb R^n}$ and  $f\circ f^{-1}\circ id_{\mathbb R^m}=id_{\mathbb R^n}$ are smooth. Therefore, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth. So $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: You have proved that $f$ is a homeomoprhism, which is not necessarily a diffeomorphism. So you haven't yet proved that $E$ is a smooth manifold. But you're getting closer.

Comment: @Deane I've just finished my proof.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Notice that it's not really a proof. As your proof indicates, we **choose** the atlas $\mathcal{A}$ to be the set of linear isomorphisms $f:  E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. This is an atlas, because given any two such maps $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{A}$, the map $f_2\circ f_1^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism. Using this atlas, $E$ is now a well defined smooth manifold.

Comment: so why is my proof  not really a proof ? Is is so trivial to be called a proof ?

Comment: The point is that by the definition of a manifold and the definition of smooth maps between manifolds, any map in an atlas is a diffeomorphism. As you observe, the standard way to define $E$ as a manifold is, given any linear bijection $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow E$, define the atlas of $E$ to be $$\mathcal{A} = \{ L \}. $$ By the observation above, it immediately follows that $L$ is a diffeomorphism.

So your proof is a proof. But it can also be called a corollary of a basic fact about manifolds and smooth maps.